# How to slice array of structures into rows, not columns?

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

Consider the following.

```
a(1).x = [1 2 3];
a(2).x = [4 5 6];
```

`[a.x]` will give you `[1 2 3 4 5 6]`.

How to *easily* get `[1 2 3; 4 5 6]`. I.e. without using reshape, for example.

P.S. The syntax `[a.x;]` would be cool to have.

Comment: reshape will probably be the easiest solution...

Comment: Yea, just use reshape. I came up with `cell2mat(struct2cell(a(:))')` but I think reshape is a good an easy solution, although I would like to see if anyone comes up with something clever.

Comment: +1, just an aside, `vertcat(a.x)` and `reshape([a.x],[],2)'` have similar speeds regarding to performance (using timeit on 1:10000 vectors)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it using vertcat:

```
vertcat(a.x)

ans =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
```

Comment: Nice. So inputting a.x will essentially call vercat with two inputs (a(1).x and a(2).x)?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so would be using `struct2cell`, `cell2mat` and `squeeze`:

```
>> a(1).x = [1 2 3];
>> a(2).x = [4 5 6];
>> squeeze(cell2mat(struct2cell(a)))'

ans =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
```